# Symfony - Integrating ExtJs

Tags: symfony, extjs, controller, http-status-code-404, integration

I am trying to integrate extjs in my symfony app.

My folder structure:

```
app
bin
src
tests
var
vendor
web
    assets
        js
            - ext-all.js
            - main.js
            controller
                - controller.js
```

All js-files are included when my page loads(works fine):

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/ext-all.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/main.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/controller.js') }}"></script>
```

main.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {

    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    appFolder: 'web/assets/js',

    name: 'MyApp',

    controllers: ['controller'],

});
```

controller.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Controller', {

    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
         console.log('Initialized');
    }

});
```

When i load page, console throws 404-error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://127.0.0.1:8000/web/assets/js/controller/controller.js?_dc=1450088635533"
```

Why there is this error ?

controller.js is right where it should be or am i wrong?

Anybody could help me with this issue?

thanks and greetings!

Comment: Try adding entire path `MyApp.controller.Controller`...Also see for launch method from your main.js

Comment: hi, i changed "appFolder" to "assets/js" and there is no more 404. But i cant log anything into console usign launch or init method. can you help with this?